# Why does Voiceover read from browser tabs that aren't on screen, and how can I stop it?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac, macos-bigsur, voiceover

Lately I have been using Voiceover on my Mac frequently to verify accessibility on pages I am developing. I only start it when I am ready to use it and do not have it running the majority of the time.  Nearly every time I press Command-F5 to start Voiceover, it begins reading status text from other tabs open in the browser, including tabs that are minimized, rather than whatever I am addressing at the moment.

I realize I can stop it by pressing Control (often several times as it starts reading the next thing it has in its list), but is there any way I can prevent this behavior to begin with? I don't understand why this would be a desirable behavior at all; I don't want updates on tabs I just happen to have open but am not focused on when I start the screenreader, I want it to read what's currently on screen.

None of the options I saw in System Preferences seem to have anything to do with this behavior.

This is Big Sur 11.6.7 (20G630) if relevant, and using Chrome 105.0.5195.125.

Comment: Does it do the same in Safari?

Comment: @Tetsujin it does not.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid, my guess would be that Chrome is playing its usual game of not abiding by Mac Toolbox guidelines. I'd check maybe Firefox, Brave etc & report it as a bug.